# How to handle token refreshing in Spring Webflux WebClient

Tags: java, spring, jwt, spring-webflux, spring-webclient

I want to create some authentication service to be used for `WebClient`, so it automatically refresh the token when needed:

```
@Service
public class AuthService {

    private String token;

    private final WebClient webClient;

    private final Map<String, String> bodyValues;

    @Autowired
    public AuthService(WebClient webClient) {
        this.webClient = webClient;
        this.bodyValues = new HashMap<>();
        this.bodyValues.put("user", "myUser");
        this.bodyValues.put("password", "somePassword");
    }

    public String getToken() {
        if (this.token == null || this.isExpired(this.token) {
            this.refreshToken();
        } 
        return this.token;
    }


    private void refreshToken() {
        this.token = webClient.post()
                .uri("authEndpointPath")
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .body(BodyInserters.fromValue(bodyValues))
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(String.class)
                .block();
    }

    private boolean isExpired() {
        //implementation
    }
}
```

It gets the token correctly when it is expired. Is there a way to use it **ONLY ONCE**, without injecting it to other services? I was thinking about defining the `Bean` which uses `authService.getToken()` method:

```
@Configuration
public class CustomWebClientConfig {

    private final AuthService authService;

    @Autowired
    public CustomWebClientConfig(AuthService authService) {
        this.authService = authService;
    }  
  
    @Bean("myCustomWebClient")
    WebClient webClient() {
        return WebClient.builder()
                .defaultHeader("Access-Token", authService.getToken())
                .build()
    }
}
```

But obviously it will get the token only once at Application startup. Is there a way to inject it somehow or to intercept all of the webclient request and add the token then?

Comment: In the AuthService you are autowiring the WebClient and in the WebClient the AuthService. How did you solve the circular dependency exception? Cheers.

Comment: @xYan there is no circular dependency as in `AuthService` I autowire `WebClient` but `AuthService` is autowired within  `CustomWebClientConfig`, not `WebClient`. 


So it's like: `WebClient` ->  `AuthService` -> `CustomWebClientConfig`

Comment: That's what you get when you don't read everything. Yes sure there is no circullar, sorry for my neglect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can declare a custom `WebClient` with [filter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/reactive/function/client/ExchangeFilterFunction.html) that is applied on each request.

```java
@Configuration
public class CustomWebClientConfig {

    private final AuthService authService;

    @Autowired
    public CustomWebClientConfig(AuthService authService) {
        this.authService = authService;
    }  
  
    @Bean("myCustomWebClient")
    WebClient webClient() {
        return WebClient.builder()
                .filter(ExchangeFilterFunction.ofRequestProcessor(
                    (ClientRequest request) -> Mono.just(
                        ClientRequest.from(request)
                            .header("Access-Token", authService.getToken())
                            .build()
                    )
                ))
                .build();
    }
}
```

### EDIT

If `AuthService` also return `Mono<String>` as a token, then code will look a bit different.

```java
@Configuration
public class CustomWebClientConfig {

    private final AuthService authService;

    @Autowired
    public CustomWebClientConfig(AuthService authService) {
        this.authService = authService;
    }  
  
    @Bean("myCustomWebClient")
    WebClient webClient() {
        return WebClient.builder()
                .filter(ExchangeFilterFunction.ofRequestProcessor(
                    (ClientRequest request) -> {
                        Mono<String> tokenMono =  authService.getToken();
                        return tokenMono
                                  .map(token -> ClientRequest.from(request).header("Access-Token", token).build())
                    }
                ))
                .build();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is what I did before you replied. Anyway, I will accept your answer. Thank you :)

Comment: I tried this, but authService.getToken() has to be synchronous in order for this to work. If your getToken method uses block() or any of its variants (e.g. blockOptional) then this will fail with an error: block() is blocking, which is not supported in thread reactor-http-epoll

Comment: @Calabacin it is also possible even if `AuthService.getToken` returns `Mono<String>`. I updated my answer with example