# How to prevent requesting new access token everytime in WebClient

Tags: spring, security, oauth-2.0, webclient

We have WebClient configuration:

**application.yml**

```
security:
  oauth2:
    client:
      registration:
        custom-client:
          authorization-grant-type: client_credentials
          client-authentication-method: client_secret_post
          client-id: somedummyid
          client-secret: somedummysecret
          provider: custom-client
      provider:
        custom-client:
          token-uri: xxxxxxxxxx/token
```

**configuration class:**

```
@Configuration
public class WebClientConfig {

    @Bean
    public OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authClientManager (ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository,
                                                                           OAuth2AuthorizedClientService authorizedClientService,
                                                                           HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory) {

        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(
            Arrays.asList(new FormHttpMessageConverter(), new OAuth2AccessTokenResponseHttpMessageConverter()));

        restTemplate.setErrorHandler(new OAuth2ErrorResponseErrorHandler());
        restTemplate.setRequestFactory(new BufferingClientHttpRequestFactory(requestFactory));

        final DefaultClientCredentialsTokenResponseClient tokenResponseClient = new DefaultClientCredentialsTokenResponseClient();
        tokenResponseClient.setRestOperations(restTemplate);
        final ClientCredentialsOAuth2AuthorizedClientProvider authorizedClientProvider = new ClientCredentialsOAuth2AuthorizedClientProvider();
        authorizedClientProvider.setAccessTokenResponseClient(tokenResponseClient);
        final AuthorizedClientServiceOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager =
            new AuthorizedClientServiceOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager(
                clientRegistrationRepository, authorizedClientService);

        authorizedClientManager.setAuthorizedClientProvider(authorizedClientProvider);

        return authorizedClientManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public WebClient customWebClient(@Qualifier("authClientManager") OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager,
                                         @Qualifier("requestReactorFactory") ReactorClientHttpConnector connector,
                                         @Value("${baseUrl}") String baseUrl) {
        ServletOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction oAuth2Filer = new ServletOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction(authorizedClientManager);
        oAuth2Filer.setDefaultClientRegistrationId("custom-client");

        return WebClient.builder()
            .clientConnector(connector)
            .filter(oAuth2Filer)
            .baseUrl(baseUrl)
            .build();

    }
}
```

And we have a service where we execute WebClient to call another service:

```
@Service
public class CustomService {

private WebClient webClient;

    public CustomService(@Qualifier("customWebClient") WebClient webClient) {
        this.webClient = webClient;
    }


    private execute() {
      return webClient.post()
        .uri("xxxxx")
        .body(xxxx)
        .retrieve()
        .bodyToMono(xxx)
        .block();
   }

}
```

**Problem:**

We have some bulk trigger where we have few thousand requests in a minute. Due to this fact, we fall into some limits on the service to which we make requests to.

**Question:**

How can we store/cache somehow access token retrieved by 1st api call , and maybe make it valid for some specific time? We want to avoid few thousand requests for a new token in 1 minute..

Comment: Are you sure of the time to live of the token you retrieve ?

Comment: We can set it up on this resource service settings. We can have there specific time  like few hours or we can make it valid until is not refreshed.

Comment: I mean, what is the current setup ?

Comment: We have a service, let's say service-A from which we do perform api calls (code is above) to the service-B. 

service-B has configured refresh token policy and set it as: Refresh token valid until revoked.

We want to avoid refreshing token in service-A every time a new request is executed in service class (webclient.post()/get()). As mentioned above, we have a trigger that calls thousand separate request and we fall in a limit forced by service-B (there is some max number auth calls per minute/hour).

Comment: What is the token validity duration ?

Comment: @Zorglube with current config, it is valid until is revoked so there is no specified time.

Answer (score 1):

To anyone who is looking for some solution. I found some useful post here:

[How to handle token refreshing in Spring Webflux WebClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71620124/how-to-handle-token-refreshing-in-spring-webflux-webclient?fbclid=IwAR028dKlSvxBSeDGFWmQ958uC63v0zT1D-UAdRMWVdGVo0vq1aAj-TFg39k)

And solved my problem by creating custom service where I'm checking if access_token is valid and decide to refresh or keep old value.

When it comes to WebClient, we can simply put token value to the header (check highlighted answer from above post).